# CSS Grid with IE11

Tags: css, sass, autoprefixer

As far as I understand, IE11 needs `grid-column` and `grid-row` properties to be set.
As long as you use `grid-template-areas`, you can rely on Autoprefixer to convert areas to `grid-column` and `grid-row`, which is great.

In my case, I'm not using areas to define my grid, I'm just repeating columns with the same pattern:

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0,1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
```

So, I'm thinking of the best way to implement CSS grid support on my grids for IE11. It basically means: setting `grid-column`and `grid-row` on each grid wrapper children.

Right now, I'm considering using a good old Sass loop to render a set of CSS rules, like that:

```
$column: 1;
@for $i from 1 through 100 { // 100 = just a large amount that I'll never reach
 $row: ceil($i/3); 
 .grid-item:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {  
    grid-column: #{$column};
    grid-row: #{$row};
  }
  $column: $column + 1;
  @if $i % 3 == 0 {
    $column: 1;
  }
}
```

I think that should do the trick. But I'm not sure that's a *good* solution. If I could I would stick to a non-Sass solution, just using Autoprefixer.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need indeed to tell each element where to stand in IE. auto-flow doesn't work , you have no other choice.

Comment: you can also filter IEs wich doesn't supports auto-flow and set another layout tech  via `@supports (grid-auto-flow: row) { /* your grid layout here overwriting previous table/float or flex layout */}`  see https://caniuse.com/#search=%40supports

Comment: `@supports` is indeed a better way to implement my big Sass loop, I'll surely use it.